# Ошибка при выделении памяти

Tags: память, c++

Здравствуйте все!

Есть несколько потоков, в которых периодически создаются и удаляются объекты

```
class SiteInfoData {
    public:
        SiteInfoData() {
            site = new char[256];
            link = new char[768];
        }

        ~SiteInfoData() {
            delete[] site;
            delete[] link;
        }

        int num;
        char* site;
        char* link;
            //....

};

SiteInfoData * a = new SiteInfoData();
//...
delete a;
```

В разных местах в разное время на new вываливается access violation в borlndmm.dll. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такое может быть и как это исправить :) Спасибо!

Comment: Нет-ли проблем с синхронизацией? Поправь в коде:
 delete[] site;
 site = NULL;
 delete[] link;
 link = NULL;

И смотри на ошибки доступа к нулевому указателю.

Comment: Возможно вызывается конструктор копирования по умолчанию, из-за чего происходит обращение к уже освобождённой памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- В коде, который вы привели, **нет потенциальных ошибок.** Ищите их либо в `//...`, либо в механизмах синхронизации, которые вы используете.
- Потенциально возможность ошибки может быть в `non-thread-safe` `malloc` *(а, следовательно, и `new`)*. Можете для проверки обернуть их с помощью какого-нибудь механизма сихронизации. То есть, здесь ситуация следующая - потокобезопасность `malloc'a` является `implementation-specific`, а значит, в принципе, он [может быть не `thread-safe` на отдельно взятой платформе.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe)

> All the answers so far answer **"is malloc thread-safe?"**, which is entirely different question. To that question the answer is it depends on your runtime library, and possibly on the compiler flags you use. On any modern `UNIX` you'll get a thread-safe malloc by default. On `Windows,` use `/MT`, `/MTd`, `/MD` or `/MDd` flags to get thread-safe runtime library.

- Вероятность того, что в рантайме `Borland` используется непотокобезопасный `malloc` достаточно низка, однако, возможно, стоит это проверить.

> Больше *(с учетом того фрагмента кода, который вы запостили)* зацепиться не за что.